# Dynamics CRM Online Navigation pane shows only Settings and Service

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

In Dynamics CRM Online, my account has System Admin role. I would like to customize our solution for Sales and Marketing teams. When I login, however, I only see 'Settings' and 'Services' in the navigation panes and don't see 'Sales' and 'Marketing' panes. I have privileges to customize the entities (lead, account etc), but I would like to be able to see these in my Navigation. These used to show by default.
Any ideas on how to show those? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you been upgraded to latest release that dropped the left-side nav for the top bar?

Comment: If you have rights then maybe you can take a look at the `sitemap` and see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

As Piyush pointed out use one of sitemap editrs i.e.:

http://sitemapeditor.codeplex.com/

http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2013/08/06/dude-where-39-s-my-site-map-editor.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me when I provisioned a CRM 2013 Online (free trial). What worked for me was creating another System Administrator user. The sitemap and the other areas were visible as expected when I logged in as the new user.

Answer (score 0):

Goto: https://portal.office.com/UserManagement

In **licenses** section add check **Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online Professional** ans Save.
[image]
This will solve your problem.

//waqas